createComposeRule() for another file while testing Compose Multiplatform UI
I have a desktop app. Its source code is a lot of composable functions in separate *.kt files, for example
@Composable
fun MyView()
    ...

And now I have to write an UI test for these functions in another file.
@OptIn(ExperimentalTestApi::class)
@get:Rule
val rule = createComposeRule(???)

I found an example for Android app UI testing:
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)          

But in my desktop Compose Multiplatform app I have no activities. How can I use MyView() function while creating a compose test rule in this case?

createComposeRule doesn't take any parameters, is a factory function.
There's a good document for how to use this function and compose tests in general.
Create the rule
@get:Rule val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

(In a test) Apply your content to the rule
composeTestRule.setContent {
    MainScreen(uiState = fakeUiState, /*...*/)
}

Test the visibility of some node
composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("Welcome").assertIsDisplayed()

Edit
If the above doesn't work with compose for desktop I recommend looking into the JetBrains test library.
@OptIn(ExperimentalTestApi::class)
@Test
fun myTest() = runComposeUiTest {
    setContent { MainScreen(uiState = fakeUiState, /*...*/) }
    onNodeWithTag("text").assertTextEquals("Compose")
}


Thank you! It works for me!
And should I add semantic tags for all my controls generated by composable functions to access them here in the rule?
